# How to change total bundle identifiers in unity android project?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games, bundle-identifier

**My basement and I want**
I already made and published a game to google playstore. (assume it's bundle identifier is *com.mycompany.mygame1*)
And I want start my next game project from last game's copy.
my unity version is 2018.2.5f1 and using internal (not gradle) build.
my last game(mygame1) has plugins that gpg, admob.

**my working**
Make new game console page and gpg service console page.
Make a new git repository and copy Assets, ProjectSettings folder from last project.
Using Same unity version.
And I Changed nexts.
1) change bundle identifier to new game's in inspector>build settings>other settings>package name (assume the new bundle identifier is *com.mycompany.mygame2*)
2) create a new jks keystore file and set it inspector>build settings>publishing settings
3) simply find and replace all text *mygame1* to *mygame2* in the every *AndroidManifest.xml*
4) copy achievement resource from new google play service console to editor>window>Google Play Games>Setup>Android Setup, and press Setup button.

**My Problem**
but when i doing 4), editor asks to me that;

```
Set Bundle Identifier?
The server configuration is using com.mycompany.mygame1, but the player setting is set to com.mycompany.mygame2. Set the bundle Identifier to com.mycompany.mygame1?
Ok / Cancel
```

So I Pressd Cancel. because I don't want using *mygame1*.

But it generates *ProjectSettings/GooglePlayGameSettings.txt* file with bundle identifier *com.mycompany.mygame1*.

I think there's must be place with stores previous bundle identifier.

So I search every file recursively with text *mygame1* using TotalCommander.
And it said 2 results.

ProjectSettings/GooglePlayGameSettings.txt
  ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset

the first one is generated file (based some *hidden* stored bundle identifier).
and second one is binary so i can't hack it.

**Question**
I don't know where *com.mycompany.mygame1* stored.
Someone help me how to find and change the hidden bundle identifier, please.

**P.S.**
At this state, It can generate signed apk and it runs well, surprisingly.
But I still afraid that editor stores other bundle identifier.

Comment: You can modify the bundle identfier in ProjectSettings.asset that way: Edit > Project Settings > Player > Android > Other Settings > Package Name. You might want to change it for all platforms since this field is separate by each platform.

Comment: ProjectSettings.asset is only binary, because its configured that way. You can change it in Edit > Project Settings > Editor > Asset Serialization to "Text only". This will also reserialize all your assets (materials, prefabs, etc.) in text format called YAML.

Comment: But this is not your issue, the error messages comes from [play-games-plugin-for-unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/source/PluginDev/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/GPGSAndroidSetupUI.cs). Which says your Google Play Games project still  linked to com.mycompany.mygame1. Check under **Linked apps** if the issue is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you for all comments.

I already changed package name.
but I finally found the answer from your 2, 3rd comments.

First, **Close** Unity Editor.
And delete *ProjectSettings/GooglePlayGameSettings.txt* file.
And I also deleted Library, obj, Packages folder for make it cleary. (I think it might not needed.)

And restart unity and change platform to android, editor says 'gpgs ready to use'.
And Doing 4) is completely work!

I think the editor holds old parsed *ProjectSettings/GooglePlayGameSettings.txt* data in memory.
So make bundle identifier and gpgs setting clear, turn off unity editor needed.